# Error org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression when execute a Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I got this error when execute my Futtler app

> org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Can't find
>   ']' to match '['. [

I fix the error in the specific class but it still appears.

Answer (score 2):

I use Tools -> Flutter -> flutter clean, and it works!